# Sign a PDF form with iTextSharp

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I have a PDF Form which has a signature field of known name root[0].containerpage[0].footer[0].SignatureField1[0]
Also i have a PFX certificate.
Now the question is, I have the form open in itextsharp's PdfStamper, how do I sign it so that

- the form is locked to changes
- the signature status is visible in the mentioned field

---

I have come up with the following code:

```
Dim pk12 As Pkcs12Store = New Pkcs12Store(New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "cert.pfx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "pass".ToCharArray())
Dim i As IEnumerator = pk12.Aliases()
While (i.MoveNext())
    cert_alias = (i.Current)
    If (pk12.IsKeyEntry(cert_alias)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End While
Dim akp As AsymmetricKeyParameter = pk12.GetKey(cert_alias).Key
Dim ce As X509CertificateEntry() = pk12.GetCertificateChain(cert_alias)
Dim chain() As X509Certificate( **%PROBLEM%** )
For k As Integer = 0 To ce.Length
    chain(k) = ce(k).getCertificate()
Next
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("pdf.pdf")
Dim stamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, New FileStream("pdf.pdf", "pdf_signed.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), "\0")

Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
appearance.SetVisibleSignature("mySig")
appearance.Reason = "Its personal."
appearance.Location = "Foobar"
appearance.SetCrypto(pk12, chain, Nothing, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED)
appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED

appearance.Acro6Layers = True
appearance.SignatureGraphic = Image.GetInstance(RESOURCE)
appearance.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.Graphic


stamper.Close()
```

cannot however figure out what on earth should go in the **X509CertificateStructure** as param of X509Certificate where it says **%PROBLEM%** in the code block.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
Dim chain() As X509Certificate(ce.length)
```

I always get confused with VB and array size declaration so you might have to subtract 1

Comment: Yes, it has to be (-1) but i still can't seem to understand how the actual process works - for me it doesn't work right. Is there any further reading I could do on this topic? Thanks